# UITapGuesture CGMakeRect invisible frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

Is it possible to create an invisible frame on a view and add a UITapGuesture to it?

Comment: Invisible frame? Set view background color to clear color.

Answer (score 0):

Possible. You can add subview to your view with needed frame and set `subview.backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: Make sure the `userInteractionEnabled` is `YES` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create an invisible view with same frame as your parent view. Set its background clear color and add it to parent view.

```
UIView *invisibleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:parentView.frame];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnInvisibleFrame:)];
[invisibleView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[invisibleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[parentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[parentView addSubview:invisibleView];
```

**Alternate Solution:**

It is advise or take as an alternative.

I don't know what is your requirement to use tap gesture. If requirement is not stick with tap gesture than one alternative is there for above.

Create `UIButton` object with the same frame of your parent view. Set its type to custom type, by default it will be invisible to you. And you can use selector on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` which will work same as tap gesture.

How ever choice is yours.

```
UIButton *invisibleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[invisibleButton setFrame:parentView.frame];
[invisibleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(invisibleButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[parentView addSubview:invisibleButton];
```